# Convert an integer to an enum value

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
type ActorState int

const (
    Unverified ActorState = 1 + iota
    Verified
    Banned
)
```

And I want to do this in my implementation.

```
i := 1
a : ActorState 
a = ActorState(i)
```

But I get the error, `Cannot convert expression of type int, error to type ActorState`.

How do I convert it then?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you mean

```
i := 1
a := ActorState(i)
```

or

```
i := 1
var a = ActorState(i)
```

or

```
i := 1
var a ActorState
a = ActorState(i)
```

Comment: Worth noting, you can elide the var type in the second one.  `var a = ActorState(i)` is perfectly legal. https://play.golang.org/p/PI0ZXYf940